# How to Implement Facebook Oauth with Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth

I want to Implement Facebook Oauth with Zend in my site.

My requirement is ,"Use Facebook for authentication and authorization when user login using Facebook in site".

Kindly provide some example link/tutorial.

Comment: Can any one give simple example link ?

Comment: Is it possible to access Facebook via OAuth with the Zend Framework ?

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297667/zend-framework-zend-oauth-and-zend-service-twitter

Answer (score 0):

some nice examples here http://socialdevelopers.net/

Comment: Thanks.Can you suggest me download example link ?

Comment: sorry, didn't dig enough about that, hope someone else could help you more

Comment: okay venimus.http://www.jasperrooswinkel.com/facebook-oauth-20via-graph-api-using-php-and-zend-framework/ I checked this link having some tutorial.But I did not get it works

Comment: i suppose you should already have working site with proper user handling before using oauth, because the main idea is to skip users from entering their data manually in your site, but instead use the data from facebook, but you still have to make a registration for the user in your DB. That most examples do not cover, because it is up to you to do it.